# The target group with targetGroupArn does not have associated load balancer error

Tags: amazon-ecs, target

I'm running two scripts, one that creates a cluster with the required resources, and then another script to create the tasks and service.  The first script creates everything correctly, but when I run the second script to create the service and task, it gives the following error:

The target group with targetGroupArn arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:ca-central-1:XXXXXXXXX:targetgroup/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX does not have an associated load balancer. (Service: AmazonECS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterException; Request ID: 3899fd23-3eee-473f-9914-453a8d669f14)

What am I doing wrong?

Script 1 to create cluster:

AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'

Description: A stack for deploying containerized applications onto a cluster of EC2

```
         hosts using Elastic Container Service. This stack runs containers on

         hosts that are in a public VPC subnet, and includes a public facing load

         balancer to register the services in.
```

Parameters:

DesiredCapacity:

```
Type: Number

Default: '3'

Description: Number of EC2 instances to launch in your ECS cluster.
```

MaxSize:

```
Type: Number

Default: '6'

Description: Maximum number of EC2 instances that can be launched in your ECS cluster.
```

ECSAMI:

```
Description: AMI ID

Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<AWS::EC2::Image::Id>

Default: /aws/service/ecs/optimized-ami/amazon-linux-2/recommended/image_id
```

InstanceType:

```
Description: EC2 instance type

Type: String

Default: t2.micro

AllowedValues: [t2.micro, t2.small, t2.medium, t2.large, m3.medium, m3.large,

  m3.xlarge, m3.2xlarge, m4.large, m4.xlarge, m4.2xlarge, m4.4xlarge, m4.10xlarge,

  c4.large, c4.xlarge, c4.2xlarge, c4.4xlarge, c4.8xlarge, c3.large, c3.xlarge,

  c3.2xlarge, c3.4xlarge, c3.8xlarge, r3.large, r3.xlarge, r3.2xlarge, r3.4xlarge,

  r3.8xlarge, i2.xlarge, i2.2xlarge, i2.4xlarge, i2.8xlarge]

ConstraintDescription: Please choose a valid instance type.
```

Mappings:

# Hard values for the subnet masks. These masks define

# the range of internal IP addresses that can be assigned.

# The VPC can have all IP's from 10.0.0.0 to 10.0.255.255

# There are two subnets which cover the ranges:

#

# 10.0.0.0 - 10.0.0.255

# 10.0.1.0 - 10.0.1.255

#

# If you need more IP addresses (perhaps you have so many

# instances that you run out) then you can customize these

# ranges to add more

SubnetConfig:

```
VPC:

  CIDR: '10.0.0.0/16'

PublicOne:

  CIDR: '10.0.0.0/24'

PublicTwo:

  CIDR: '10.0.1.0/24'
```

Resources:

# VPC in which containers will be networked.

# It has two public subnets

# We distribute the subnets across the first two available subnets

# for the region, for high availability.

VPC:

```
Type: AWS::EC2::VPC

Properties:

  EnableDnsSupport: true

  EnableDnsHostnames: true

  CidrBlock: !FindInMap ['SubnetConfig', 'VPC', 'CIDR']
```

# Two public subnets, where containers can have public IP addresses

PublicSubnetOne:

```
Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet

Properties:

  AvailabilityZone:

     Fn::Select:

     - 0

     - Fn::GetAZs: {Ref: 'AWS::Region'}

  VpcId: !Ref 'VPC'

  CidrBlock: !FindInMap ['SubnetConfig', 'PublicOne', 'CIDR']

  MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true
```

PublicSubnetTwo:

```
Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet

Properties:

  AvailabilityZone:

     Fn::Select:

     - 1

     - Fn::GetAZs: {Ref: 'AWS::Region'}

  VpcId: !Ref 'VPC'

  CidrBlock: !FindInMap ['SubnetConfig', 'PublicTwo', 'CIDR']

  MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true
```

# Setup networking resources for the public subnets. Containers

# in the public subnets have public IP addresses and the routing table

# sends network traffic via the internet gateway.

InternetGateway:

```
Type: AWS::EC2::InternetGateway
```

GatewayAttachement:

```
Type: AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment

Properties:

  VpcId: !Ref 'VPC'

  InternetGatewayId: !Ref 'InternetGateway'
```

PublicRouteTable:

```
Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable

Properties:

  VpcId: !Ref 'VPC'
```

PublicRoute:

```
Type: AWS::EC2::Route

DependsOn: GatewayAttachement

Properties:

  RouteTableId: !Ref 'PublicRouteTable'

  DestinationCidrBlock: '0.0.0.0/0'

  GatewayId: !Ref 'InternetGateway'
```

PublicSubnetOneRouteTableAssociation:

```
Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation

Properties:

  SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnetOne

  RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable
```

PublicSubnetTwoRouteTableAssociation:

```
Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation

Properties:

  SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnetTwo

  RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable
```

# ECS Resources

ECSCluster:

```
Type: AWS::ECS::Cluster
```

# A security group for the EC2 hosts that will run the containers.

# Two rules, allowing network traffic from a public facing load

# balancer and from other hosts in the security group.

#

# Remove any of the following ingress rules that are not needed.

# If you want to make direct requests to a container using its

# public IP address you'll need to add a security group rule

# to allow traffic from all IP addresses.

EcsHostSecurityGroup:

```
Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup

Properties:

  GroupDescription: Access to the ECS hosts that run containers

  VpcId: !Ref 'VPC'
```

EcsSecurityGroupIngressFromPublicALB:

```
Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress

Properties:

  Description: Ingress from the public ALB

  GroupId: !Ref 'EcsHostSecurityGroup'

  IpProtocol: -1

  SourceSecurityGroupId: !Ref 'PublicLoadBalancerSG'
```

EcsSecurityGroupIngressFromSelf:

```
Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress

Properties:

  Description: Ingress from other hosts in the same security group

  GroupId: !Ref 'EcsHostSecurityGroup'

  IpProtocol: -1

  SourceSecurityGroupId: !Ref 'EcsHostSecurityGroup'
```

# Autoscaling group. This launches the actual EC2 instances that will register

# themselves as members of the cluster, and run the docker containers.

ECSAutoScalingGroup:

```
Type: AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup

Properties:

  VPCZoneIdentifier:

    - !Ref PublicSubnetOne

    - !Ref PublicSubnetTwo

  LaunchConfigurationName: !Ref 'ContainerInstances'

  MinSize: '1'

  MaxSize: !Ref 'MaxSize'

  DesiredCapacity: !Ref 'DesiredCapacity'

CreationPolicy:

  ResourceSignal:

    Timeout: PT15M

UpdatePolicy:

  AutoScalingReplacingUpdate:

    WillReplace: 'true'
```

ContainerInstances:

```
Type: AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration

Properties:

  ImageId: !Ref 'ECSAMI'

  SecurityGroups: [!Ref 'EcsHostSecurityGroup']

  InstanceType: !Ref 'InstanceType'

  IamInstanceProfile: !Ref 'EC2InstanceProfile'

  UserData:

    Fn::Base64: !Sub |

      #!/bin/bash -xe

      echo ECS_CLUSTER=${ECSCluster} >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config

      yum install -y aws-cfn-bootstrap

      /opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $? --stack ${AWS::StackName} --resource ECSAutoScalingGroup --region ${AWS::Region}
```

AutoscalingRole:

```
Type: AWS::IAM::Role

Properties:

  AssumeRolePolicyDocument:

    Statement:

    - Effect: Allow

      Principal:

        Service: [application-autoscaling.amazonaws.com]

      Action: ['sts:AssumeRole']

  Path: /

  Policies:

  - PolicyName: service-autoscaling

    PolicyDocument:

      Statement:

      - Effect: Allow

        Action:

          - 'application-autoscaling:*'

          - 'cloudwatch:DescribeAlarms'

          - 'cloudwatch:PutMetricAlarm'

          - 'ecs:DescribeServices'

          - 'ecs:UpdateService'

        Resource: '*'
```

EC2InstanceProfile:

```
Type: AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile

Properties:

  Path: /

  Roles: [!Ref 'EC2Role']
```

# Role for the EC2 hosts. This allows the ECS agent on the EC2 hosts

# to communciate with the ECS control plane, as well as download the docker

# images from ECR to run on your host.

EC2Role:

```
Type: AWS::IAM::Role

Properties:

  AssumeRolePolicyDocument:

    Statement:

    - Effect: Allow

      Principal:

        Service: [ec2.amazonaws.com]

      Action: ['sts:AssumeRole']

  Path: /

  Policies:

  - PolicyName: ecs-service

    PolicyDocument:

      Statement:

      - Effect: Allow

        Action:

          - 'ecs:CreateCluster'

          - 'ecs:DeregisterContainerInstance'

          - 'ecs:DiscoverPollEndpoint'

          - 'ecs:Poll'

          - 'ecs:RegisterContainerInstance'

          - 'ecs:StartTelemetrySession'

          - 'ecs:Submit*'

          - 'logs:CreateLogStream'

          - 'logs:PutLogEvents'

          - 'ecr:GetAuthorizationToken'

          - 'ecr:BatchGetImage'

          - 'ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer'

        Resource: '*'
```

# Load balancers for getting traffic to containers.

# This sample template creates one load balancer:

#

# - One public load balancer, hosted in public subnets that is accessible

#   to the public, and is intended to route traffic to one or more public

#   facing services.

# A public facing load balancer, this is used for accepting traffic from the public

# internet and directing it to public facing microservices

PublicLoadBalancerSG:

```
Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup

Properties:

  GroupDescription: Access to the public facing load balancer

  VpcId: !Ref 'VPC'

  SecurityGroupIngress:

      # Allow access to ALB from anywhere on the internet

      - CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0

        IpProtocol: -1
```

PublicLoadBalancer:

```
Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer

Properties:

  Scheme: internet-facing

  #LoadBalancerAttributes:

 # - Key: idle_timeout.timeout_seconds

   # Value: '30'

  Subnets:

    # The load balancer is placed into the public subnets, so that traffic

    # from the internet can reach the load balancer directly via the internet gateway

    - !Ref PublicSubnetOne

    - !Ref PublicSubnetTwo

  #SecurityGroups: [!Ref 'PublicLoadBalancerSG']
  Type: network
```

# A dummy target group is used to setup the ALB to just drop traffic

# initially, before any real service target groups have been added.

DummyTargetGroupPublic:

```
Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup

Properties:

  HealthCheckIntervalSeconds: 10

  #HealthCheckPath: /

  HealthCheckProtocol: TCP

  #HealthCheckTimeoutSeconds: 5

  HealthyThresholdCount: 2

  Name: !Join ['-', [!Ref 'AWS::StackName', 'drop-1']]

  Port: 80

  Protocol: TCP

  UnhealthyThresholdCount: 2

  VpcId: !Ref 'VPC'
```

PublicLoadBalancerListener:

```
Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener

DependsOn:

  - PublicLoadBalancer

Properties:

  DefaultActions:

    - TargetGroupArn: !Ref 'DummyTargetGroupPublic'

      Type: 'forward'

  LoadBalancerArn: !Ref 'PublicLoadBalancer'

  Port: 80

  Protocol: TCP
```

# This is an IAM role which authorizes ECS to manage resources on your

# account on your behalf, such as updating your load balancer with the

# details of where your containers are, so that traffic can reach your

# containers.

ECSRole:

```
Type: AWS::IAM::Role

Properties:

  AssumeRolePolicyDocument:

    Statement:

    - Effect: Allow

      Principal:

        Service: [ecs.amazonaws.com]

      Action: ['sts:AssumeRole']

  Path: /

  Policies:

  - PolicyName: ecs-service

    PolicyDocument:

      Statement:

      - Effect: Allow

        Action:

          # Rules which allow ECS to attach network interfaces to instances

          # on your behalf in order for awsvpc networking mode to work right

          - 'ec2:AttachNetworkInterface'

          - 'ec2:CreateNetworkInterface'

          - 'ec2:CreateNetworkInterfacePermission'

          - 'ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface'

          - 'ec2:DeleteNetworkInterfacePermission'

          - 'ec2:Describe*'

          - 'ec2:DetachNetworkInterface'



          # Rules which allow ECS to update load balancers on your behalf

          # with the information sabout how to send traffic to your containers

          - 'elasticloadbalancing:DeregisterInstancesFromLoadBalancer'

          - 'elasticloadbalancing:DeregisterTargets'

          - 'elasticloadbalancing:Describe*'

          - 'elasticloadbalancing:RegisterInstancesWithLoadBalancer'

          - 'elasticloadbalancing:RegisterTargets'

        Resource: '*'
```

## These are the values output by the CloudFormation template. Be careful

## about changing any of them, because of them are exported with specific

## names so that the other task related CF templates can use them.

Outputs:

ClusterName:

```
Description: The name of the ECS cluster

Value: !Ref 'ECSCluster'

Export:

  Name: !Join [ ':', [ !Ref 'AWS::StackName', 'ClusterName' ] ]
```

ExternalUrl:

```
Description: The url of the external load balancer

Value: !Join ['', ['http://', !GetAtt 'PublicLoadBalancer.DNSName']]

Export:

  Name: !Join [ ':', [ !Ref 'AWS::StackName', 'ExternalUrl' ] ]
```

ECSRole:

```
Description: The ARN of the ECS role

Value: !GetAtt 'ECSRole.Arn'

Export:

  Name: !Join [ ':', [ !Ref 'AWS::StackName', 'ECSRole' ] ]
```

PublicListener:

```
Description: The ARN of the public load balancer's Listener

Value: !Ref PublicLoadBalancerListener

Export:

  Name: !Join [ ':', [ !Ref 'AWS::StackName', 'PublicListener' ] ]
```

VPCId:

```
Description: The ID of the VPC that this stack is deployed in

Value: !Ref 'VPC'

Export:

  Name: !Join [ ':', [ !Ref 'AWS::StackName', 'VPCId' ] ]
```

PublicSubnetOne:

```
Description: Public subnet one

Value: !Ref 'PublicSubnetOne'

Export:

  Name: !Join [ ':', [ !Ref 'AWS::StackName', 'PublicSubnetOne' ] ]
```

PublicSubnetTwo:

```
Description: Public subnet two

Value: !Ref 'PublicSubnetTwo'

Export:

  Name: !Join [ ':', [ !Ref 'AWS::StackName', 'PublicSubnetTwo' ] ]
```

EcsHostSecurityGroup:

```
Description: A security group used to allow containers to receive traffic

Value: !Ref 'EcsHostSecurityGroup'

Export:

  Name: !Join [ ':', [ !Ref 'AWS::StackName', 'EcsHostSecurityGroup' ] ]
```

Script 2 to create service and task:

AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'

Description: Deploy a service into an ECS cluster behind a public load balancer.

Parameters:

StackName:

```
Type: String

Default: PublicNLBCluster2

Description: The name of the parent cluster stack that you created. Necessary

             to locate and reference resources created by that stack.
```

ServiceName:

```
Type: String

Default: nginx

Description: A name for the service
```

ImageUrl:

```
Type: String

Default: nginx

Description: The url of a docker image that contains the application process that

             will handle the traffic for this service
```

ContainerPort:

```
Type: Number

Default: 80

Description: What port number the application inside the docker container is binding to
```

ContainerCpu:

```
Type: Number

Default: 256

Description: How much CPU to give the container. 1024 is 1 CPU
```

ContainerMemory:

```
Type: Number

Default: 512

Description: How much memory in megabytes to give the container
```

Path:

```
Type: String

Default: "*"

Description: A path on the public load balancer that this service

             should be connected to. Use * to send all load balancer

             traffic to this service.
```

Priority:

```
Type: Number

Default: 1

Description: The priority for the routing rule added to the load balancer.

             This only applies if your have multiple services which have been

             assigned to different paths on the load balancer.
```

DesiredCount:

```
Type: Number

Default: 2

Description: How many copies of the service task to run
```

Role:

```
Type: String

Default: ""

Description: (Optional) An IAM role to give the service's containers if the code within needs to

             access other AWS resources like S3 buckets, DynamoDB tables, etc
```

Conditions:

HasCustomRole: !Not [ !Equals [!Ref 'Role', ''] ]

Resources:

# The task definition. This is a simple metadata description of what

# container to run, and what resource requirements it has.

TaskDefinition:

```
Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition

Properties:

  Family: !Ref 'ServiceName'

  Cpu: !Ref 'ContainerCpu'

  Memory: !Ref 'ContainerMemory'

  TaskRoleArn:

    Fn::If:

      - 'HasCustomRole'

      - !Ref 'Role'

      - !Ref "AWS::NoValue"

  ContainerDefinitions:

    - Name: !Ref 'ServiceName'

      Cpu: !Ref 'ContainerCpu'

      Memory: !Ref 'ContainerMemory'

      Image: !Ref 'ImageUrl'

      PortMappings:

        - ContainerPort: !Ref 'ContainerPort'
```

# The service. The service is a resource which allows you to run multiple

# copies of a type of task, and gather up their logs and metrics, as well

# as monitor the number of running tasks and replace any that have crashed

Service:

```
Type: AWS::ECS::Service

DependsOn: PublicLoadBalancerListener

Properties:

  ServiceName: !Ref 'ServiceName'

  Cluster:

    Fn::ImportValue:

      !Join [':', [!Ref 'StackName', 'ClusterName']]

  DeploymentConfiguration:

    MaximumPercent: 200

    MinimumHealthyPercent: 75

  DesiredCount: !Ref 'DesiredCount'

  TaskDefinition: !Ref 'TaskDefinition'

  LoadBalancers:

    - ContainerName: !Ref 'ServiceName'

      ContainerPort: !Ref 'ContainerPort'

      TargetGroupArn: !Ref 'TargetGroup'
```

# A target group. This is used for keeping track of all the tasks, and

# what IP addresses / port numbers they have. You can query it yourself,

# to use the addresses yourself, but most often this target group is just

# connected to an application load balancer, or network load balancer, so

# it can automatically distribute traffic across all the targets.

TargetGroup:

```
Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup


Properties:

  Name: !Ref 'ServiceName'

  Port: 80

  Protocol: TCP

  VpcId:

    Fn::ImportValue:

      !Join [':', [!Ref 'StackName', 'VPCId']]
```

Comment: First thing to debug would be : is the target group even associated with your application load balancer ? Do you see a mapping already in the web console ?

Comment: I just checked in my console, when I click on the target group :  Load balancer
clust-Publi-1QE..... , i takes me to the Network Load balancer I created using the script above. So they are associated according to the web console.

Comment: I had the same issue. After adding a `DependsOn: targetGroup` at the service, it went away.